# How to refer Kubernetes env variable to another service in the same cluster?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I'm running service based on `vault` image(ingress with an endpoint, name is 'vault' too) inside my kubernetes cluster, and I want another app to take vault's service host/port inside. Here is the part of my `deployment` config:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 45
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my_app_test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my_app_test
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: maxrybalkin91/my_app_test:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: my_app_test
          env:
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test
                  key: vault_token
            - name: VAULT_HOST
              value: $(vault_SERVICE_HOST)
            - name: VAULT_PORT
              value: $(vault_SERVICE_PORT)
```

My `bootstrap.yml` file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
      fail-fast: true
      config.lifecycle.enabled: false
      scheme: http
      host: ${VAULT_HOST}
      port: ${VAULT_PORT}
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}
```

The problem is that my deployment can't find such variable, and the app is failing with parsing ${VAULT_PORT} inside the port, seems like it doesn't find it at all.
How to add the value from my service inside the yaml config correctly?
Should it be also added to selectors?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple. I just needed to upcase my `$(vault_SERVICE_HOST)` to `$(VAULT_SERVICE_HOST)`